# How to response dynamicly set of fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm litter new in Django and I want to know how to dynamically return a set of fields by user type e.g. if user is a `Manager` so can get all the fileds in the model he requested but if the user is a `Clerk` they could see just some fields of the model that the manger specified and these set of fields are in a table for updating in the future.

for more information I want to filter this model base on user type:

```
class LandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

user = UserSerializer()
utm_points = UTMPointsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Land
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'activity_field','activity_location',
        'area', 'part', 'location','verification_code', 'verified', 
        'description', 'approved', 'receipt_bank_name', 'receipt_serial', 
        'receipt_date', 'receipt_amount','utm_points', 'image')
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'approved',)

def create(self, validated_data):        
    user = validated_data.pop('user')
    user = User.objects.create(**user)
    user.save()

    land = Land.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
    land.save()
    return land
```

Manager can get all the fields but other users have just access to some fields regard to this is the manger that specifies which user type can see which set of fields

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far (*Models, Views, Templates etc.*)?

Comment: I havn't done much things because I dont know how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **APIView**  with returning `Response` object, you can determine what to be shown to user.
Here is how to use `Response` object:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.responses import Response
from rest_framework import status

class TestAPIView(APIView):
    
    def post(self, request):

        # Some logic for getting objects and determining fields

        # dict is a dictionary including data to be shown to user
        return Response (data=dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

It'll be fine if your request method is **POST**, because the method used in **APIView** is `post`.

If your request method is **GET** you can change this method name to `get`

Comment: Thanks for your advice